# Get NID of newly created node from entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I need to pull the nid immediately after it is created using entity_metadata_wrapper as a creation method.

Here is a brief example:

```
$values = array(
  'type' => 'content_type',
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'status' => 1,
  'comment' => 1,
  'promote' => 0,
);

$entity = entity_create('node', $values);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
$wrapper->title->set('title');
$wrapper->save(true);
entity_save('node', $entity); 

// From this, where can I get a NID value for the node that was just created?
```

Comment: If you have devel module installed than can you check what does this returns: `dpm($wrapper);`.
Otherwise try the following code:
echo '<PRE>'; print_r($wrapper); echo '</PRE>';

Comment: Just a note, but you don't need `$wrapper->save()` and `entity_save()` - just one will suffice, else you're saving the node twice. Also, nid will be added to the wrapper after save, e.g `$wrapper->nid->value();`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can simply use the entity_metadata_wrapper's integrated method to get the ID:

```
$wrapper->getIdentifier()
```

Answer (score 6):

Easy.

```
 $wrapper->save();
 $node = $wrapper->value();
 dsm($node); // which has $node->nid;
```

Figured I'd answer for somebody else to use.

**Update:**

The answer above is a better answer `$wrapper->getIdentifier()`.

There are situations when the entity may have some sort of unique identifier.

Comment: The next answer show the right ways to do this stuff. `$wrapper->getIdentifier()`

Comment: Thanks, and you're right.  I've updated my answer to reflect it as so :)